# How do i change the DragManager reject-symbol in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a drag-n-drop functionality in flex4/as3, for the first time. I use the DragManager-class, and the basic drag-and-drop stuff works now. But, how do i change the little red "reject cursor" which is displayed when i drag objects over areas where i can't drop it?

I can find "rejectCursor" in the styles specification here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/DragManager.html#styleSummary

But I have no idea about how to set in in AS3. Do i have to use css, and if yes, could you give me a quick example? Would be very helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `<fx:Style>` tag to declare the global style:

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

    mx|DragManager {
        rejectCursor: Embed('path/to/icon.pngORswf');
    }

</fx:Style>
```

**Edit:** To do this from an AS3 class instead of from MXML, you would use:

```
import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
import mx.styles.IStyleManager2;
import mx.styles.CSSStyleDeclaration;

[Embed('path/to/icon.pngORswf')]
private var rejectCursor:Class;

var mgr:IStyleManager2 = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.styleManager;
var selector:String = "mx.managers.DragManager";
var decl:CSSStyleDeclaration = mgr.getStyleDeclaration(selector);
if (!decl)
    decl = new CSSStyleDeclaration(selector);
decl.setStyle("rejectCursor", rejectCursor);
mgr.setStyleDeclaration(selector, decl, false);
```

Comment: Ok, but thats mxml, isn't it possible to do the same thing in actionscript? Because the class where I want to use it is a pure as3-file. Thanks anyway!

Comment: +1 This looks like an awesome approach; I look forward to hearing if this works.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in AS3 you can set a styles on a Flex Component like this:

```
UIComp.setStyle('styleName',newValue);
```

However, since DragManager does not extend UIComponent the setStyle method does not exist.  From here, I'm guessing a bit.

If you dig into code; you'll find the DragProxy class, and a showFeedback method, which has a segment like this:

```
var styleSheet:CSSStyleDeclaration = styleManager.getMergedStyleDeclaration("mx.managers.DragManager");
newCursorClass = styleSheet.getStyle("rejectCursor");
```

So, you could try setting that style on the instance of the DragProxy; but you'll need access to the DragProxy instance.  It looks like you need to use mx_internal do that:

```
import mx.core.mx_internal;
use mx_internal
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
var myDragProxy : DragProxy = DragManager.dragProxy()
dragProxy.setStyle('rejectCursor', newValue);
```